# Does invoking bs.reload(*.html) reload all html files under the app directory?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, browser-sync

Will [browser-sync](https://browsersync.io/) reload all html files under the `app` directory when started like this in node?

```
// require the module as normal
var bs = require("browser-sync").create();

// .init starts the server
bs.init({
    server: "./app"
});

// Now call methods on bs instead of the
// main browserSync module export
bs.reload("*.html");
```

For example if we have `app/main/html/index.html` and `app/test/html/index.html`, will bs.reload("*.html") reload both of these files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will. As seen in the documentation, (https://browsersync.io/docs/api#api-reload), it will reload ALL .html files in the `app` directory.